# Windows Phone disable back button when TimeSpanPicker has focus (i.e user choosing time span)

Tags: windows-phone-8, back-button, timespan

I am currently implementing a countdown timer for a windows phone app and I am having some trouble disabling the back button when the user is choosing a time span from the TimeSpanPicker.  I only need to disable it when this is occurring and so it has to work fine apart from this.

I have the override OnBackKeyPress method with the following code inside it:

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(//user choosing duration using TimeSpanPicker)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    }
```

As you can see from the commented pseudo condition, I need a way of checking if the user is currently choosing a time span duration and if so disable the back button.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Let the user go back if he wants to! In this case keep the previously set time span. If the user wants a new one, he will reenter the time span picker screen. But if the wants to go back (maybe several times to close the app), let him do so.

Comment: I only thought to do it this way when I was trying to make the reset button more robust because when the user taps the timeSpanPicker element after a time span has initially been chosen and then clicks the back button the reset button resets the value to the value when the timeSpanPicker element was tapped and not the previous chosen time span. I'll play about with other options then, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will be rejected from the market if you completely disable the back button.

There are a number of reasons for this but the main one is that we want a consistent user experience across the platform. That's a great thing we have going for us. A user should be able to open your app and expect the buttons to function as they expect.

One acceptable reason to **override** the back button is if you are on a game screen and you want the game to pause. Another reason would be if you had a custom menu appear and the back button hides the menu. Both of these scenarios are obvious to the user.

Comment: Yeah I realise it is unacceptable to disable completely but thought this would be acceptable as it is only when temporarily choosing a time span from the timeSpanPicker element. I'll play about with other options then, thanks for your help.

Comment: @JamesTwigg A good rule of thumb is "If something you're doing flies in the face of what is a standard, then you likely need to rethink your architecture." I know it's hard to do that sometimes but you will grow as a developer if you take the time to do this.

Comment: I appreciate the advice @Anthony Russell and will most definitely take it on board, thanks.